# I have trouble with the latest Android Studio Gradle Update 3.3.1

Tags: android, gradle, warnings

I have recently switched to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'` and wrapper properties is set to `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.10.1-all.zip`.

I am using following dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2'
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:$playServicesVersion"
    implementation 'com.roomorama:caldroid:3.0.0'
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:design:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:$supportLibraryVersion"
    implementation "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife"
    annotationProcessor "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife"
    implementation 'com.balysv:material-ripple:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
    annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
    // retrofit dependency
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:$retrofit"
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava:2.0.2'

    // rx dependency
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.2.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex:rxjava:1.3.4'

    // network client api
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:$okhttp"
    implementation "com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:$okhttp"

    //DI dependency
    compileOnly 'javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
    implementation 'com.kbeanie:image-chooser-library:1.6.0@aar'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
    implementation 'pl.charmas.android:android-reactive-location2:2.1@aar'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.9'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:$retrofit"
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.journeyapps:zxing-android-embedded:3.5.0'
}
```

and the version numbers are specified as follows:

```
ext {
    minSdkVersion = 14
    targetSdkVersion = 22
    compileSdkVersion = 27
    supportLibraryVersion = '27.1.1'
    playServicesVersion = '12.0.0'
    versionCode = 12
    versionName = "1.74"
    butterknife = "8.8.1"
    retrofit = "2.2.0"
    okhttp = "3.7.0"
    dragger = "2.12"
}
```

I am getting these warnings, maybe due to `ButterKnife` *[`ButterKnife` is incompatible with `AndroidX` as well]*:

```
Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
API 'variant.getAssemble()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getAssembleProvider()'.
API 'variantOutput.getProcessResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessResourcesProvider()'.
API 'variantOutput.getProcessManifest()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variantOutput.getProcessManifestProvider()'.
API 'variant.getMergeResources()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeResourcesProvider()'. 
API 'variant.getMergeAssets()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getMergeAssetsProvider()'.   
API 'variant.getPackageApplication()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getPackageApplicationProvider()'. 
API 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildTasks()' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'variant.getExternalNativeBuildProviders()'.
```

**My query is that, is there something very serious, or should I ignore?**

Comment: Replace obsolete methods with new one.

Comment: I can't upgrade further or change anything. Reason is that I am using `ButterKnife`. I think it's `build.gradle` file has something to do with it, and it is `read-only`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of the answer given by @AntonisRadz, I checked one by one, as to which dependency was throwing this warning.

The warnings were due to the old version of 'Google Services', and one version of 'Crashlytics', both declared as `classpath dependencies` in the main project's `build.gradle`.

1. One should regularly update the dependencies. For help, gradle marks the dependencies with the 'yellowish' background which needs to be updated. Do an 'alt+enter' on it for the latest version number, and to update to the same, on clicking it.
2. Try to use the updated APIs and avoid the 'obsolete' or 'deprecated' ones.

The question is not related to 'Butterknife' at all as because after removing it's dependencies, the warnings were still there.

Finally, my latest project level 'build.gradle' partly looks like:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options
//common to all sub-projects/modules.
buildscript {
    repositories {
        // jcenter()
        google()
        jcenter {
            url "http://jcenter.bintray.com"
        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
        classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:4.1.1"
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.27.1'
    }
    //due to google services older version, and crashlytics latest version:
//        WARNING: Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
//                It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html
//        Affected Modules: app
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
```

Happy Coding :-)

Comment: I showed this answer to my team, to persuade them that versions should be updated, and they finally agreed.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you rollback to previous Gradle version. These are actually more than just warnings, as these might affect code editor and prevent you from searching references to classes.

Just wait until the concerned libraries are updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update Sir. I am not in the position to downgrade either just to let you know.

Comment: If you cant downgrade it then ignore it while going to get updated

Comment: Thanks! I shall be waiting for the updates regarding this.

Comment: I am still waiting for the answer my friend.

Comment: Answer is that with your given circumstance you can ignore it :)